# How to include the extra menu into sticky header?

Tags: php, wordpress

I added the extra menu (top menu bar) in WordPress website by using register menu function. And i want to place it into the sticky header. How to do that?

Already header layout in sticky header. O want to add this extra menu into the sticky header.

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('new-menu',__( 'New Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'new-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Krishnamala, could you show more code of the header or an example?

Comment: <?php if( is_singular() ) {
   global $post;
   $enable_sticky_header = rwmb_meta( 'themepixels_enable_sticky_header', '', $post->ID );
   if( $enable_sticky_header == 'default' || $enable_sticky_header == '' ) {
    if( tps_get_option('sticky_header') == '1' ) {
     get_template_part( 'framework/header/sticky-header' );
    }
   } else {
    if( $enable_sticky_header == 'yes' ) {
     get_template_part( 'framework/header/sticky-header' );
   }
  }
  } else {
   if( tps_get_option('sticky_header') == '1' ) {
    get_template_part( 'framework/header/sticky-header' );
   }
  }?>

Comment: <?php
   $header_layout = tps_get_option('header_layout');
   if( is_singular() ) {
    global $post;
    $meta = rwmb_meta( 'themepixels_header_layout', '', $post->ID );
    if( $meta == 'default' || $meta == '' ) {
     $header_layout = tps_get_option('header_layout');
    } else {
     $header_layout = $meta;
    }
   }
  ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'framework/header/header', $header_layout ); ?>

Comment: @KrishnamalaMariappan If you are able to edit your WordPress templates, you must be able to edit your question and add your properly formatted code. Pasted code in comment is unreadable. Minimal effort is required, if only out of respect for people who help you.

Comment: @ Al Foиce ѫ Sorry for your inconvenience. And thanks for your support. Actually i got the solution. I pasted code into the sticky header file. And it will work now properly.